# Get unexpected result with bind_quoted statement

Tags: elixir

I am trying to understand `bind_quoted` in macro and have following macro module:

```
defmodule Debugger do

  defmacro log(expression) do
    if Application.get_env(:debugger, :log_level) == :debug do
      quote bind_quoted: [expression: expression] do
        IO.puts "============="
        IO.inspect expression
        IO.puts "============="
        expression
      end
     else
        expression
    end
  end
end
```

Then in the shell, I play around as follow with the module

```
iex(1)> import_file "debugger_fixed.exs"
{:module, Debugger,
 <<70, 79, 82, 49, 0, 0, 6, 224, 66, 69, 65, 77, 69, 120, 68, 99, 0, 0, 0, 158, 131, 104, 2, 100, 0, 14, 101, 108, 105, 120, 105, 114, 95, 100, 111, 99, 115, 95, 118, 49, 108, 0, 0, 0, 4, 104, 2, ...>>,
 {:log, 1}}
iex(2)> require Debugger
nil
iex(3)> Application.put_env(:debugger, :log_level, :debug)
:ok
iex(4)> remote_api_call = fn -> IO.puts("calling remote API...") end
iex(7)> Debugger.log(remote_api_call.())
```

as the result on the last line, I've got

```
calling remote API...
=============
:ok
=============
:ok
```

but I expect

```
=============
calling remote API...
:ok
=============
:ok
```

I know that `bind_quoted` execute an expression only once.
My question is, can someone please explain why I've got unexpected result?

Comment: Please don't cross-post over several media, if you really have to, choose a central place and let other posts link to it!

Comment: @zero_coding May I suggest that if you're trying to learn how to use macros that an investment in Chris McCord's "Metaprogramming Elixir" would be a wise move? Seems that might help you to help yourself on these sorts of questions. Just a suggestion, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy-pasting my answer already given at [Elixirforum – Get unexpected result with bind_quoted statement](http://elixirforum.com/t/get-unexpected-result-with-bind-quoted-statement/337/2):

That is not strange and not documented as well, but if you use `bind_quoted` option to `quote/2`, it is expanded to something like this:

```
# your code
quote bind_quoted: [foo: foo] do
  IO.inspect foo
end
```

---

```
# what the compiler makes out of it in a first expansion pass of many!
quote do
  foo = unquote(foo)
  IO.inspect foo
end
```

So what gets injected in your example is about that:

```
quote do
  expression = unquote(expression)
  IO.puts "============="
  IO.inspect expression
  IO.puts "============="
  expression
end
```

Seeing it this way, should make obvious why you get your output as it is.

Even if using `bind_quoted` is much less typing, I would strongly discourage its use:

1. You gave an example above, you loose control over order of execution
2. You might loose track of which items were unquoted and which come from "inside"
3. You loose the ability to manually unquote other bindings, it is an all or nothing decission.

**edit**

And before I forget about it… Logging should be free of sideeffects (except logging ;)). So either log from your "base" function that you are going to do a remote-API-call soon, or log from you remote-API-function that you are doing the call right NOW. But don't pass a function to the logger that the logger does execute it… Due to code injections in a macro there might be a harmful change of context!

Comment: First of all, thanks very much for your answer. I forgot IO.puts return :ok and it executed before macro call. I am so stupid.

Comment: It is not executed before macro call, it is executed on every `unquote` and using `bind_quoted` you are `unquote`ing early.

Answer (score 1):

Second `:ok` is result of your expression, printed by REPL, not by your code. `IO.puts` returns `:ok`. 
As you can check in `Macro.expand`-ed code, expression is evaluated exactly once.

```
iex(9)> quote(do: Debugger.log(remote_api_call.())) |> Macro.expand(__ENV__) |>
...(9)> Macro.to_string |> IO.puts
(
  expression = remote_api_call.()
  (
    IO.puts("=============")
    IO.inspect(expression)
    IO.puts("=============")
    expression
  )
)
```

Comment: It's not the second `:ok` he is wondering about. It's the fact that the first 2 lines of the output are swapped versus his expectation. But it took me a `diff`-run as well to realize ;)

Comment: Oh. Yes, I got the question totally wrong. Not sure, should I delete this answer?..

Comment: In fact, your answer does really show, what I only have presented in a simplified manner, the fact that the argument given to the macro is unquoted before the actual content of the given `:do` block. Perhaps you can rephrase your leading sentence and make this a valid answer to the question?